# How to exclude (ignore) a GIS route programmatically in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

While working with Anylogic user can open properties of some GIS route (or some other object) and push checkbox "Ignore". The GIS route will be excluded from the model and after running the model user wont see the object because it wont exist.

Is it possible to exclude some GIS routes in interactive mode? For example I drew in Anylogic big GIS network with many GIS routes and after running the model (!) I want to have a possibility to choose routes which should not be included in the network. E.g. it can be implemented in Simulation window.

I was looking for suitable JAVA code but I did not find anything except Visible-property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not programmatically "ingore" something, this is not how Java works.

In your case, the only way is to create the GIS network programmatically as well at the start of the model. Now you have full control because you could decide to only create *part* of your network, depending on user choice.

Check the AnyLogic API on how to create GIS routes programmatically.

cheers

Comment: Your answer has helped me, it is optimal way to resolve the problem I think. Thanks!